# Why can't I retrieve the users email from Google Plus API after getting permission

Tags: php, google-plus

Using the google plus connect API I'm able to ask for permission for the users email but I don't seem to have access to it.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
require_once '../../src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Test Application");
$client->setClientId('XXXXX');
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXX');
$client->setRedirectUri('XXXXX');
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXX'); 
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'));

$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
   unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  print_r($me);

 }
```

Any idea how I retrieve the email address after the user has granted permission to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=45) for that since a while that you can star.

In the meantime you can use an authenticated request against the OAuth2 Userinfo API instead.

```
require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

(...)

$oauth2Service = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);

(...)

$userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo->get();
$email = $userinfo["email"];
```

Answer (score 2):

The email information comes through a different endpoint and requires another request. The following code should work once you're authorized:

```
$oauth2Service = new Google_Oauth2Service($client); 
$emailinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo->get(); 
print_r($emailinfo);
```

Comment: **UPDATE** According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24510214/3727907 , "auth2/v2/userinfo endpoint is deprecated, and scheduled to be removed in September 2014. It has begun working inconsistently - so don't use it."